# I'm not able to exclude a file from .text section in linker script

Tags: c, gcc, stm32, linker-scripts

```
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*blink.c.obj) .text .text*) /* Exclude blink from this section */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH


  _load_flash_start = _etext; /* define a global symbol that starts at LOAD_FLASH */
  .fast_code_section:
  {
    /*. = ALIGN(4);*/
    . = _etext;
    _fast_code_start = .;                   /* define a global symbol at start of FAST_RAM */
    *(.fast_code_section*)
    *blink.c.obj (.text .text*)
    _fast_code_end = .;                     /* define a global symbol at end of FAST_RAM */
  } >FAST_RAM AT> LOAD_FLASH
```

I want to exclude the file blink.c to be allocated into .text section (FLASH), by using the EXCLUDE_FILE in linker script.
And I want the blink.c file in another section (.fast_code_section).

When I look in the .map file I can see that all functions in blink.c is still allocated to .text section.

i'm using gcc and the target platform is a stm32

Comment: Why not just remove the file from the liker script/makefile?

Comment: because I still want the file, but I have another section where I will place it

Comment: The easiest way place them into another section instead of .text.

Comment: How do you mean? Isn't that what I've done? to .fast_code_section

Comment: in what section do static functions get placed? Is it also in the .text section by default?

Comment: @bei, you can specify in the C file where a function is placed. Seomthing li,ke `void funct(....) __attribute__ ((section (".mysection")));`

Comment: thanks, but I know, I don't want to add __attribute__ to all functions since it is quite many functions in the file, and instead include/exclude the whole file to a specific section